# Qt Access Webcam on Linux OS without downloading any package

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am looking for some Links/Tutorials/Examples to Access my Webcam on Linux OS without downloading any packages.

Actually, I am working on a very compact OS (with already removed unnecessary packages).We are space conscious for this project.

I tried OpenCv (on other machine with full OS version) and it worked fine for me but its package is more than 100 Mb and in my project i cant afford that much space. Also, since many packages are already removed from this OS (to make it compact), I am unable to install Opencv on my machine to test it(Because of its missing dependencies).

So I wonder, Is there any other way to access webcam without downloading any packages??

Adding headers/files would be fine in my case.

Any help, suggestion would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could take a look at [libwebcam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libwebcam/).  I haven't used it myself, but it's _way_ smaller, with a 128k source tarball.  Seems to require the kernel headers, libxml2, and (possibly) gengetopt to build.

Comment: Thanks Xavier, I tried your suggestion. It seems that some packages/files are missing with this software.As i tried to compile, it gives errors related to package.Even though i tried it on latest Ubuntu 12.04 and installed all the required packages.
Also, i am using ubuntu 9.10 for my project.
Anyway Thanks alot, I will do more research on this.

Comment: The size of development packages (e.g. some `libfoo-dev` on Debian or Ubuntu) is not related to the size of the user packages (`libfoo`). The development packages are usually bigger, and they are needed to compile and build your software, not to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To capture image on linux, without downloading any heavy packages is possible through command line using "uvccapture".UVCCAPTURE is in Kb size. And The two line code can capture image.

for example:

```
QProcess process
process.execute(/usr/bin/uvccapture -v -m -o"test.jpg");
```

Comment: For live-video /video capturing, it need mplayer/vlc etc and can be operated in a similar manner through command line.